Putting rust dependency crates into shared library
In Rust crates are usually statically bound into resulting binaries.
But I have several binaries (cgi ‚scripts‘ of a Webserver on an embedded device) that basically all have the same dependencies in Rust crates. But with static linking this results in (relatively) big binaries that in fact have most of the code in common.
Is it possible to create a shared object of all the dependency crates that they share and link to that shared object dynamically?
To elaborate a bit further on how I imagine this:
I have binaryA and binaryB and dependencies.so.
At runtime binaryA links to dependencies.so and binaryB links to dependencies.so as well.
I know this could probably be done by downloading every single dependency by hand and compiling it as a dylib then linking the rust binary with all of them. But is there an easier way? In Rust dependencies pull in dependencies and you end up with hundreds quite fast.

You can create a dynamically linked library that reexports all shared dependencies and make it dynamic like I explain in this other question

Note that a shared library created this way is not guaranteed to be sharable between different versions of the compiler or even between different invocations of it. The rust ABI is not specified.

@cafce25 yes i know, but this set of binaries is part of the Webserver package and always compiled together and shipped together. In this case there shouldn’t be a problem with incompatible ABI, right?
